# Return "Name.Value" as a String of any enumerated type without workarounds?

Tags: ios, swift, string, macos, enums

Say I have some Swift enum, `JavaSwift`, that is a replicated instance of some JavaScript file rewritten in Swift:

```
enum JavaSwift {
  case voidFunc                   // function voidFunc() { ... }
  case boolFunc(_ : Bool)         // function boolFunc(_ : boolean) { ... }
  case enumFunc(_ : JSEnum)       // function enumFunc(_ : JSEnum) { ... }
  
  enum JSEnum {
    case demo
    var id: String { return "JSEnum.\(self)" }
  }
}

// MARK: Raw JavaScript -
extension JavaSwift {
  var js: String {
    switch self {
    case .voidFunc: return "voidFunction();"
    case .boolFunc(let n): return "boolFunction(\(n));"
    case .enumFunc(let n): return "enumFunction(\(n.id));"
    }
  }
}
```

Such that I can call:

```
func run(_ script: JavaSwift) { script.js }
run(.voidFunc)         // "voidFunc();"
run(.boolFunc(true))   // "boolFun(true);"
run(.enumFunc(.demo))  // "enumFunc(JSEnum.demo);"
```

As are with all cases here, `JSEnum` is defined in JavaScript (albeit, transpiled from TypeScript). The function, `enumFunction(_ : JSEnum)`, requires the call be made with the syntax:

`enumFunction(JSEnum.caseValue)    // ie. JSEnum.demo`

Thus, the demo call I'm attempting to make above can be written as such:

`enumFunction(.demo).js    // returns "enumFuncton(JSEnum.demo);"`

#### Actual Question

Although it isn't much of a hassle to use the workaround above – `var id: "EnumName.\(self)"` – I'm eventually going to be automating this generation process, as well as applying the same method to a number of different JavaScript types.

Ideally, it would be nice to have a universal solution that would allow me to slim the call down to something like this:

```
enum JavaSwift {
  case voidFunc
  case boolFunc(_ : Bool)
  case enumFunc(_ : JSEnum)

  enum JSEnum: String {
    case demo    // no additional String variable required
  }
}

// MARK: Raw JavaScript -
extension JavaSwift {
  var js: String {
    switch self {
    case .voidFunc: return "voidFunction();"
    case .boolFunc(let n): return "boolFunction(\(n));"
    case .enumFunc(let n): return "enumFunction(\(n));"  // No need to call "n.id"
    }
  }
}
```

I've been playing around with the syntax all morning, but Xcode seems to be having some caching issues with previously defined functions. It will return an error if I change the syntax around, requiring an application restart.

If you have any other suggestions on how I could improve this code, I'm all ears! For example, would it be possible to embed the JS-defined enum within the case declaration itself? Furthermore, would it be possible to rid the extended `var js: String` altogether?

At the end of the day, this file will be returning Strings of raw JavaScript code in a type-safe manner that will one day be automated. I'm aiming to generalize the syntax as much as possible before starting the generator code.

It would be neat to make the Swift code more JavaScripty (but strictly for these no-touch, automated files of JS code).

Comment: Are you writing some sort of a JavaScript code generator?

Comment: @Sweeper Trying to, at least!

Comment: Semi-related rambling: I don't think the `.id` is an issue in itself. The name might be a bit cryptic, but you're expressing that there's a conversion going on, from a Swift value to some JavaScript representation. I think ti's good to keep that. I would add a protocol like `CustomJavaScriptConvertible` that has a `var asJavaScript` property. Make  `Bool`, `JSEnum`, and other desired types conform to it. When generating code, call `asJavaScript` on the value to generate.

Comment: You can then extend `RawRepresentable where rawValue: CustomJavaScriptConvertible`, so that enums can automatically have that `var id: String`, "inherited" from the extension

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for the awesome writeup! I've been trying to implement your words into code for the last few minutes (still a little rusty with Swift syntax and recursive inheritance), will get back to you when I can get the syntax down right and code working!

Comment: @Alexander any chance you'd have a few minutes this week to help me write that out in full Swift (and possibly explain how step of the inheritance works?). No rush at all and no worries if you can't find time! I'm just finding that I've gotten to the point where I'm trying to combine different code to make it work. Not understanding what's actually going on with he Swift code at the fundamental level.

Comment: "Not understanding what's actually going on with he Swift code at the fundamental level." Which Swift code?